# Passing text from mysql to javascript on JSP page

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have a block of text I store in a mysql table as longtext and then I retrieve using struts bean:define for jsp.  I want to retrieve this block of text for use in a jquery UI dialog which means the text must be parsed with the "\n" characters.  Currently the text comes out like

```
emailMSG[1] = "%fn %ln,

Our records indicate that certification in %gn, %cn, %sn expire(d) on %dt.

Please take the refresher course.

Please visit our portal to log into your training.

Please ignore any messages from CITI regarding course expiration. DO NOT log in directly to the CITI site.";
```

I need the data to be in this format:

```
emailMSG[<%=id%>] = "%fn %ln,\n"+
"\n" +
"Our records indicate that certification in %gn, %cn, %sn expire(d) on %dt.\n"+
"\n" +
"Please take the refresher course at the training site.\n"+
"\n" +
"Please visit our portal to log into the site.\n"+
"\n"+
"Please ignore any messages from CITI regarding course expiration. DO NOT log in directly to the CITI site.";
```

How can I get the "\n"+ characters in the data coming out of the mysql table?

Here is the bit of my code that references this part (I removed the non relevant pieces):

```
<logic:iterate id="cel" name="CourseEmailList" scope="request">
    <bean:define id="msg" property="message" name="cel" scope="page" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <bean:define id="id" property="id" name="cel" scope="page" type="java.lang.String"/>
<tr>
        <logic:notEmpty name="cel" property="message" scope="page">
            <td><a href="#" onclick="OpenDialog(<bean:write name='cel' property='id' scope="page"/>);return false;">View/Modify</a>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                courseIDs[<%=id%>] = "<%= id%>";
                emailMSG[<%=id%>] = "<%= msg%>";
            </script>
            </td>
        </logic:notEmpty>
        </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  There may be a simpler way to do it but here's what I did:

1) I wrote a java function to replace all the /r/n in the data from the database with %nl.  I call this on each line in the result set when I store my query results for use on the jsp page.

```
public static String formatMessage(String comment) {
        if(comment != null){
            return comment.replaceAll("\r\n", "%nl");
        }else{
            return "";
        }
  }
```

2) Then on my jsp page I took the bean:define data and saved it to a temporary variable then did a str.replace function globably replacing all the %nl with \n.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var temp = "<%= msg%>";
      var parsed = temp.replace(/%nl/g,'\n');
      emailMSG[<%=id%>] = parsed.valueOf();
</script>
```

This made my text appear correctly in the jquery ui dialog text area.